# A1342 MacBook distorted speaker motherboard issue

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, speakers

I have an A1342 MacBook I cobbled together from spare parts. It works perfectly except the rear speaker atop the optical drive outputs distorted audio. The two speakers underneath the keyboard work perfectly. I also verified the speaker itself isn't the problem by taking a good speaker from another working MacBook. All audio from that speaker on the motherboard outputs distorted audio: the startup tone, the beep code when no ram is installed, etc. Resetting the PRAM didn't accomplish anything. The speaker connector on the motherboard looks fine (it's not loose or broken). What on the motherboard is causing interference with the speaker circuit? Why is this happening?

Thanks.

Comment: The "removable" speaker???  As for what would cause distorted audio...look for dry/broken solder joints or poor connections between the audio driver and the speaker.  It could also be bad/blown capacitor(s) and/or resistor(s).  Without having a trained tech put hands on, it's impossible to give an accurate answer.

Comment: I described it as removable because it can be removed since it is only screwed in place. The other two speakers are sandwiched in the keyboard.

Comment: Using that logic... **everything** is removable.  You just need a screwdriver.

Comment: Resoldering the joins on the connector might be worth a try. I'll also have to find where the audio driver is on the board. However, wouldn't the audio driver also be responsible for the palm rest speakers and the audio jack? Everything audio works perfectly except this one speaker line.

Comment: @allen, yep I probably could have described it better. it was the best I could think of at the time.

Comment: Yes, the audio driver is responsible for all speakers - left and right, but there are different traces....

Comment: The speaker you're referring to is the **rear** speaker.  https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Unibody+Model+A1342+Rear+Speaker+Replacement/1705

Comment: I guess the driver can't be the problem? I don't quite understand how the speakers are mapped out relative to the driver since there are three speakers (only one of which isn't working). Each receives a unique signal however so perhaps there are unique outputs to each speaker from the driver. Yep, that is the correct speaker, didn't quite know the name for it when I wrote the question.

Comment: Maybe the traces to that particular speaker are messed up. Thanks for the idea. I'll take another look at the board.

Comment: Become familiar with [BoardViewer](http://boardviewer.net/) and [Rossman training videos](https://www.youtube.com/user/rossmanngroup/playlists)

Comment: @allen thanks. I've seen several of his videos. I didn't know it was a training series. The board viewer looks really helpful!